# Bittorrent up-to-date library written in python

Tags: python, client, bittorrent

Is there any up-to-date bittorrent library which is written in python and can be used on windows to write client? Some time ago bitcomet was written in python and it was ok. Any alternatives?

And second question: does bittorrent protocol change? For example what may happen if I will use old bitcomet library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main bittorrent client, from bittorrent.com is all python based I believe. I have hacked it in the past, and it's very clean code easy to modify.

Comment: can you provide some link or example of usage?

Comment: You want the 5.3 tar gz version, looks like they went proprietary after that.

Comment: the curses versions are the ones I used in the past.

Comment: ok, last question: what may be the consequences of using this version? is it possible that some torrents would not download /upload properly?

Comment: Hard to say, you'd need to check the change log. I'm guess xml torrents might not work, but I'm fairly certain 99% of torrents will work.

Comment: I can confirm that you'll have no issues using older versions of Bittorrent. Bittorrent has excellent backwards compatibility.